Unable to extract images/figures from DocumentIntelligence analyze document client method for docx and pptx files
I have a docx file with text,tables and images.
When I'm using the Document intelligence "Document analysis layout tool"
https://documentintelligence.ai.azure.com/studio/layout, I'm getting json output but in that there is are no "figures" information.
For the same docx file, if I first convert it into pdf and then analyze it, I'm getting the figures information correctly.
This is the link to docx file: https://www.mtsac.edu/webdesign/accessible-docs/word/example03.docx
Is there a bug in API version 2024-02-09 ? Why in the docx format the figures are not being detected? Same is the case with pptx format.
Sample output of docx file when run through Document Analysis Layout:

Sample output of the docx file after converting it to .pdf format and then run through Document Analysis Layout:


The Document Intelligence Layout API can extract text, tables, selection marks, and structure information from documents and images. However, it does not extract figures or images. This is why you are not seeing figures in the JSON output when analyzing your docx file. If you need to extract figures or images from your document, you may need to use a different API or tool. One option could be to use the Azure Computer Vision API, which can extract text, handwriting, and other information from images.

As for the issue with pptx files, the Document Intelligence Layout API supports PDF, TIFF, JPG, PNG, and BMP file formats, but not pptx.

References:

Get started with the Document Intelligence Sample Labeling tool
Document Intelligence layout model
Document Intelligence add-on capabilities



Unable to extract images/figures from Document Intelligence analyze document client method for docx and pptx files.

I tried with the same docx file and was unable to extract images/figures from the Document Intelligence analyze document client method for docx and pptx files.
Studio:

According to MS-Document:,
The API versions 2024-02-29-preview, 2023-10-31-preview, and later have the capability to support Microsoft Office (DOCX, XLSX, PPTX) and HTML files. However, there are certain features that are not supported by these API versions.


There are no angle, width/height, and unit with each page object.
For each object detected, there is no bounding polygon or bounding region.
Page range (pages) is not supported as a parameter.
No lines object.


It is possible that figures are not found in the docx format due to the lack of support for bounding polygons or regions. This can result in data loss (figures) during analysis.
Alternatively, as an option, you need to use pdf files to extract images/figures from the Document Intelligence analyze document client method.
